# Flex Box Sticky Footer Content Overflow

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

There seems to be alot of this around. Here is a simple jsfiddle where the footer sticks to the bottom but when the content overflows, the footer does not move to the bottom. I would like the footer to move to the bottom when the content expands.

html:

```
<body>
<div id="header">This is a Header</div>
<div id="content">asdfasdfasdfadsf
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>dasdfsfsa
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>dasdfsfsa
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>dasdfsfsa

</div>
<div id="footer">This is a Footer</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
body {
min-height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
#header {
background-color: red;
min-width: 100%;
}
#content {
background-color: white;
flex: 1;
}
#footer {
background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deadpickle/njvzjgje/2/

Comment: are the heights of the header and footer dynamic or fixed?

Comment: I suppose dynamic. In my own stuff the header would usually be a percent height.

Comment: I think you're confusing what the flex model is meant for. If you want overflow of content, then you ditch the flex model (or use it in other elements). Also, using flex on body could lead to very unexpected results, unless you're using extremely simple and "naked" layouts

Comment: SO If I want a sticky footer I should not use a flex box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your 100% height rule on the `body` element. You have the minimum height constraint, so just remove that.

But leave the 100% height on `html` if you want to make this work on Safari 5.x (which doesn't support `vh` units). So you should have something like this:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}

html, body{  
  min-height: 100%;  // older browser
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```